# The Marshaller does not writing to the xml file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jaxb, marshalling

I am learning web services and currently I am learning the JAXB in Tomcate6.0 environment. I have a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
<user>
    <email>bill@hotmail.com</email>
    <name>Bill Gates</name>
    <password>blahblah</password>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
<user>
    <email>joe@bloggs.com</email>
    <name>Joe Bloggs</name>
    <password>foobar</password>
    <gender>male</gender>
</user>
</users>
```

and this file is located in WEB-INF/users.xml.

I have a class called Blog.java which has two fields:

```
private Users users;
private String filePath;
```

and in this class I have this method:

```
public void setFilePath(String filePath) throws JAXBException, IOException {
    this.filePath = filePath;

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    this.users = (Users)u.unmarshal(fin);
    fin.close();
}
```

to set the path and users.

And this method:

```
public void saveUser(String filePath) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
      // Boilerplate code to convert objects to XML...
      JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
      Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
      m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
      m.marshal(users, fos);
}
```

to write to a xml file in the "filePath" given.

And finally in my registration page I have gathers user data and went to register the user in another page where I have coded these:

```
....
<% String filePath = application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/users.xml");%>
....
User user = new User(....);
Blog blog = new Blog();
blog.setFilePath(filePath);
blog.getUsers().addUser(user);//this is a method in Users class to add a user to a list
blog.saveUser(filePath);
....
```

However, this is not changing the users.xml file in WEB-INF/users.xml at all. Can anyone give me some advice where I have missed.

thank you

Comment: You're doing all this in a JSP?? *Makes sign of cross and backs slowly away*. P.S. if Tomcat could write to it's webapp directory don't you think that would constitute just a small security risk?

Comment: At this sage of learning security is not concerned at all as this is just a lab session, yes the pages are generated by JSP